# find multiple occurrences of the string 'pop' within a random string A using python for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean

if I have a random string A,
How can I write a Python code that will output the number of times 'pop' appears in A?

For example if A='vghedfgegopopopaeegdopopopgvepopopop', then the resulting code should output "The number of times pop appears is 7".
[picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRS5C.jpg) 
/ [and I got the wrong answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Y2q.jpg). I am expecting the occurrence to be 10, not 16.

Can you hint at what I did incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: A picture of your code is not helpful, can you copy/paste it into your question?

Comment: @jsbueno That is not a duplicate as the accepted answer doesn't account for overlapping substrings (as is the case in this question).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - when asking, your code should be pasted as text, and formatted with the  ` { } ` button. The question was closed because it was equal or similar to the one linked too.
Your code however have more problems than that - try putting a `print(char)` statement inside your loop so you can start understanding better the nature of loops.

Comment: There are answers there that do account for overlapping substrings.